# Exception has occurred: KeyError not found in axis

Tags: python, pandas, csv

This was working yesterday, tried to do it with a new file today, and its providing this error.

I'm trying to drop rows that has specific characters (gifs, gif) in them within that column.

My code is

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("Hete Output.csv", index_col ="C")
  
# dropping passed values
data.drop(["gifs", "gif"], inplace = True)
data.to_csv("Hete Output 1.csv")
```

According to panda https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html?highlight=drop is claims the axis is either index or columns. So when I tried

```
data.drop(["gifs", "gif"], inplace = True, axis = "Any value/character here")
```

I would get Exception has occurred: ValueError No axis named [] for object type DataFrame

So I'm not sure how to go about this.

Comment: `axis` can only equal `0`, `1`, `index`, or `columns`, nothing else.

Comment: @BeRT2me so would that mean I would have to eliminate the other columns until the index_col equates to 0 or 1?

Comment: See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Consider using [`Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) to filter out rows with specific strings in specific column.

Answer (score 0):

- `df.drop()` is used to drop *whole rows* or *whole columns*.
- To drop a column, you specify it by column name like: `df.drop(['col_name'], axis=1)`
- To drop a row, you specify it by index value/number like: `df.drop([0])`

  - (This can be made dynamically with a mask)

It's not clear which of these you're actually trying to drop. If you update your question to include a working example of input and desired output, I can help you work that out.

Comment: I'm trying to drop a row that has specific characters in their cells. I thought I could drop all rows that align within a specific column, then move to another column, that repeat that row drop.

Comment: Please *show* what you mean, typing the same thing again isn't helping you be more clear.

Comment: how should I show you to make it more clear because I'm not sure how to be more clear with what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I can not run `pd.read_csv("Hete Output.csv", index_col ="C")`. Make an example that I *can* run.